# Relation of trace and matrix derivatives

Tags: calculus, matrices, derivatives, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus

I've been trying to calculate the gradients of a neural network for backpropagation and I used chain rule which didn't work because of dimensions of the matrices. Then I found that the trace function along with differantials can be used to calculate the correct derivatives, I tried and succesfully found the correct ones as below:

$$A:B=tr(A^TB)$$
$$O = J(W_2^TW_1^TX)$$
$$\eqalign{\frac{\partial O}{\partial W_1} &= \nabla J : dO \cr
&= \nabla J : dW_2^T(W_1^TX) + W_2^T(dW_1^TX + W_1^TdX) \cr
&= \nabla J : dW_2^TW_1^TX + W_2^TdW_1^TX + W_2^TW_1^TdX \cr
&= \nabla J : dW_2^TW_1^TX + \nabla J : W_2^TdW_1^TX + \nabla J : W_2^TW_1^TdX \cr
&= \nabla JX^TW_1 : dW_2^T + W_2\nabla JX^T : dW_1^T + W_1W_2\nabla J : dX \cr
&= (W_2\nabla JX^T : dW_1^T)^T \cr
&= X\nabla J^TW_2^T: dW_1 \cr
&= X\nabla J^TW_2^T}$$

I can calculate it but I am lost looking for an explaination . Why and how is trace related to matrix derivatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better definition of the Frobenius product is
$$G:dX = \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n G_{ij}\;dX_{ij}$$
The fact that this can **also** be written in terms of a well-known matrix function is an unfortunate *coincidence*.

The intent of demonstrating the equivalent trace formula is to make things seem more familiar, but it usually has the *opposite* effect and confuses things further.

As an antidote to this confusion, consider the analogous formula
for third-order tensors
$${\cal G}\,\therefore\,d{\cal X} = \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^p {\cal G}_{ijk}\;d{\cal X}_{ijk}$$
which cannot be re-written in terms of any of the standard matrix functions, including the trace.

Comment: Although I agree with this answer, I'd add that the $\mathop{tr}(A^{T}X)$ notation can be useful in many circumstances when combined with the cyclic property of multiplication within a trace.  e.g. $x^{T}Ax=\mathop{tr}(A^{T}(xx^{T}))$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it doesn't explain _how_ trace is related to matrix differantiation, which was my question.

Comment: @BerkayGünaydın It's not $-$ that's the whole point of my answer. There really is no _deep_ meaning that you're missing. It's merely a coincidence that it can be written in terms of the trace.

Comment: @greg I understand but I still have questions. If trace is not related to this at all, then Frobenius product is? What I want to learn is how matrix derivatives are calculated like this, doesn't matter if it uses trace or any other function. What is the logic on calculating the gradients as I showed?

Comment: @BerkayGünaydın Assume that a second-order tensor $Y$ is a known function of a third-order tensor $X$. Then the derivative information is equally well captured by either a gradient (an fifth-order tensor) or a _differential_  
$$
G_{ijk\ell m} = \frac{\partial Y_{ij}}{\partial X_{k\ell m}}
 \quad\iff\quad 
dY_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^K\sum_{\ell=1}^L\sum_{m=1}^M G_{ijk\ell m}\;dX_{k\ell n}
$$ The important point is that in the differential every component of $dX$ must be summed over. While in the gradient, none of the indexes are summed over.